# How to fix HTTPS Certificate Error when running ASP.NET Core web app in VSCode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, https, ssl-certificate

I have move to using VSCode instead of VS2019 but noticed this error comes up when I run.. It still works.. I just need to keep clicking to ignore the error. Is there some easy fix for this ?

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Visual Studio installs a certificate for localhost. wondering if there's a way to do the same from VS Code. have you been able to figure it out?

Comment: surprised I couldn't find an easy answer since it must be happening to a lot of people.. I just switched back to VS2019 .. ended up really missing intellisense things for c#

Comment: I had the same issue and I fixed it using the command that I've shared in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` and confirm the dialog
3. Close VSCode
4. Close all browser instances

To find more information, take a look at:

- [Trust the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate on Windows and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos)

You may find the following commands useful:

- Clear developer certificate: `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`
- Generate a developer certificate: `dotnet dev-certs https`
- Trust developer certificate: `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Comment: Command is `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`

Comment: @GJ Correct. Thanks for catching that!  (I don't remember if --clear was really supported that time or it was a typo )